# Cpanel Nginx still Listening on port 80

Tags: nginx, cpanel, varnish

I am using shared hosting, with Cpanel,
I want to install varnish cache server beside Nginx,
I already installed Nginx with SSL, and it is working perfect, but to install varnish I need to configure it to listen on port 80 , so I changed the Nginx's port to 8080 , but the problem is nginx still listening on port 80 , even I changed the port in all my virtual server , this is the result of nginx -T |grep "listen "

```
listen 8080;
    listen       8080;
#   listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
    listen 8080;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 8080;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 8080;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 8080;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
```

it is showing that no port 80 in all my servers in nginx, but when I run this command

> lsof -i :80

it shows that nginx is still listening on it
sudo lsof -i :80

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   11802   root   11u  IPv4 18752179      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   12227   root   11u  IPv4 18752179      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   12246 qsinav   11u  IPv4 18752179      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   12247 qsinav   11u  IPv4 18752179      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   12249 qsinav   11u  IPv4 18752179      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   12252 qsinav   11u  IPv4 18752179      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   12253 qsinav   11u  IPv4 18752179      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   12254 qsinav   11u  IPv4 18752179      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   12255 qsinav   11u  IPv4 18752179      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   12256 qsinav   11u  IPv4 18752179      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   12257 qsinav   11u  IPv4 18752179      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   12258 qsinav   11u  IPv4 18752179      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

so from where can I prevent nginx to listen on port 80

Answer (score 0):

```
nginx -T
```

Displays the nginx offline configurations

while

```
lsof -i :80
```

Displays the real time open ports

Difference between configured environment and real-time environment means often means the service has not been restarted after configuration changed.

So simply just:

restart nginx

```
systemctl restart nginx
```